# Function() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given, I didn't use a class

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong.

So I bind the Enter key to a button and that button basically closes the window, but it always has this error:

> TypeError: CloseLoginForm() takes 0 positional arguments but 1
> was given

But it works normally when I bind the Enter key to the login button.

Every solution about this error that I can see all includes a class but I don't use any class in my codes.

```
def ShowLoginForm():
   global loginform
   loginform = Toplevel()
   loginform.title("Staff Login")
   LoginForm()

def LoginForm():
   btn_cancel = Button(loginform, text="Cancel", command=CloseLoginForm)
   btn_cancel.pack()
   btn_login = Button(loginform, text="Login", command=Login)
   btn_login.grid()

   btn_cancel.bind('<Return>', CloseLoginForm)

def CloseLoginForm():
   loginform.destroy()
```

Comment: This will requires a [mcve]. Button callbacks aren't given arguments, so it's hard to see how the code shown would produce the observed error.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that the function you pass as `command` needs to be one that takes one argument. You'll need to check the docs for Tkinter to check that that is the case. Even if you don't use that argument, you'll still need to make sure your function takes if it is the case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As it turns out, you had the right idea as regards OP's issue. However, a) this question is a duplicate, so it doesn't need to be answered here; b) it's better to be reasonably confident when posting an answer - i.e., check the docs yourself, and cite the relevant portion.